# How to append different PubSub objects and flatten them to write them altogether into bigquery as a single JSON?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I wanted to write three attributes (data, attributes and publish time) of a Pub/Sub message to Bigquery and wanted them to print in a flattened way so that all elements writes in a single row, for example:

| data[0] | data[1] | attr[0] | attr[0] | key | publishTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | attr | attr | key | publishTime |

I'm currently using the following piece of code for decoding and parsing the message but this is applicable only for the data part of the Pub/Sub message:

```html
class decodeMessage:
    def decode_base64(self,element):
        """Decode base64, padding being optional."""
        return json.dumps(element.data.decode("utf-8"))

class parseMessage:
    def parseJsonMessage(self,element):

        return(json.loads(element))
```

I've also tried merging two json after dumping them from Json objects to Json string but it didn't go as planned, my ultimate goal is to bring all columns into a single JSON with the schema retained.

I hope my question remains clear to you!
Thanks!

Comment: Data being the payloads, correct? So you want to convert multiple Pub/Sub messages into a single row on BigQuery (assuming it from data[0, data[1], etc? I am just confused on how you can make sure the schema would fit a dynamic number of records. Have you looked at this: [Writing to BigQuery](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-bigquery)?

Comment: Yes, data being the payload or we can say the PubSub object we get when read from a subscription using a IO connector in Apache beam, I just wanted a way to append PubSub message payload and PubSub message attribute in a single json, so that it can be written to bigquery, as bigquery can interpret a single JSON.

Comment: I think if you can post the pipeline code instead of only decodeMessage and parseMessage it will be beneficial. You are choosing to use only the `element.data` part, I don't see why you couldn't use `element.attributes` and concatenate it together before doing `json.dumps`.

Comment: I've added the code for you and I hope it helps you to further explain me!

Comment: I think it's better to convert your PubSubMessage to `Dict` and then write the result to `Bigquery`. How do you think about that ?

Comment: Thanks for bringing me out the solutions again and again and keeping my motivation at par!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the following problem is to simply make a Python dictionary and append all the data into a new Dictionary.

example:

```
    payload = dict()
    data = json.dumps(element.data.decode('utf-8'))
    attributes = json.dumps(element.attributes)
    messageKey = element.message_id
    publish_time = (element.publish_time).timestamp()*1000
    
    payload['et'] = publish_time
    payload['data'] = data
    payload['attributes'] = attributes
    payload['key'] = messageKey
    
    return (payload)
```